# Is there a way to see the full build log in Flash Builder 4.7?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, build, air, flash-builder

I am working on a Flex 4.9.1 / Air 3.4 project for iPad. 
This project compiles and runs fine on the Air Simulator, however when trying to deploy on the iPad (with proper certificates and provisionning and all that fun stuff), I get the following error :

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:


[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
java.io.IOException: PLIST generation failed due to SAX error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;     lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromString(Plist.java:351)
at com.adobe.air.Plist.newFromFile(Plist.java:325)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setSDKVersion(IPAOutputStream.java:1070)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.setPlatformSDKLocation(IPAOutputStream.java:971)
at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.setDeviceSDKDirectory(IPAPackager.java:187)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseFileAndPathArguments(ADT.java:1423)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseDescriptorAndFileset(ADT.java:1474)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseInput(ADT.java:929)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parsePackage(ADT.java:672)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:570)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)
```

Unfortunately this message is not showing the real cause.
As far as I can tell, all the XML files in my projects are perfectly fine, all starting with :

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

with no spaces nor funny character in front.

I haven't been able to reproduce the proper command line, because it seems like Flash Builder is doing some magic that I can't figure out.
I also tried to install (twice) SourceMate to generate an Ant script, but it totally screwed up my Flash Builder installation.

So would any of you have a trick for my  that I could use to have to full build log so that I can figure out what's going on ?
Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but your comment about Flash Builder magic got me thinking.  In your *-app.xml file, in the <initialWindow><content> tag, do you have the name of the SWF, or is it the placeholder that FlashBuilder will replace?  I'm betting that it's got the placeholder that the direct call to mxmlc isn't handling.

Comment: Hello Bill. It has indeed the placeholder (which is part of the magic, but I think there's more ... not quite sure). However I have tried by changing the placeholder and putting the swf instead but it didn't work, same error.

Comment: I couldn't find a reponse to my question, but I have succeeded to get rid of my error. I am still unsure how though. However I'm still interested to know if there is a way to have a full log of the build in flash builder.

Comment: This was due to using the wrong version of Java for the compilation in Flex Builder. Building for iOS with Java 7 doesn't work, I had to specify the system to use Java 6